# Included "has_many" in my model but I'm getitng a "ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through, has-many, join

I'm using Rails 5.1.  I'm confused about how to create a model and associations in which I have a join table that links both models.  Below is my PostGres join table for the two tables ...

```
mydb=# \d organization_workers;
                               Table "public.organization_workers"
      Column       |  Type   |                          Modifiers
-------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------
 id                | integer | not null default nextval('organization_workers_id_seq'::regclass)
 organization_id        | integer |
 stratum_worker_id | integer |
```

So then I define the models like so

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :stratum_workers, :through => :organization_workers



class OrganizationWorker < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :stratum_worker
end
```

but when I run a test that references

```
assert_false organization.stratum_workers.empty?, "A pre-condition of this test is thta the org have stratum workers."
```

I get the error

```
Error:
OrganizationTest#test_Test_total_paid:
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :organization_workers in model Organization
    test/models/organization_test.rb:7:in `block in <class:organizationTest>'
```

Comment: You have database already and you are trying to create a model based on it ? Else 

You have to define organization_workers like below 

has_many :organization_workers in organization model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first define a `has_many` for the join table itself, then you can define the `through` association. Otherwise, Rails won't know where to look to bridge the gap.

Your join model looks okay. But the models you're joining should look like this:

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :organization_workers
  has_many :stratum_workers, through: :organization_workers

end


class StratumWorker < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :organization_workers
  has_many :organizations, through: organization_workers

end
```